# Coq: cannot find length_zero_iff_nil

Tags: coq

I am trying to use the library function `length_zero_iff_nil` but I don't seem to be able to find the correct `Import` statement for coqtop to find the reference. I have looked at:
https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html
So I initially tried:

```
Require Import List.
```

Then realized `length` was said to be defined in `Coq.Init.Datatypes` so tried:

```
Require Import Datatype.
```

Then I looked at:
https://coq.inria.fr/library/index_global_L.html which suggests:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
```

None of these attempts have been successful. I could of course prove this myself as a small lemma, but as I am in the process of learning Coq (investing a few hours a day on this), I want to also learn how to use the existing library, which I am usually able to do. There is probably something I am missing here, and I'd like to learn what it is.

I am using:
"The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl4 (July 2014)
compiled on Jul 27 2014 13:34:24 with OCaml 4.01.0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lemma is new to Coq 8.5, you can see it [here](https://x80.org/collacoq/ipulagevip.coq). I recommend you update to Coq 8.5. Depending on your use case, you could also consider alternative list libraries such as [seq](http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.seq.html) and [tuple](http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.tuple.html) from math-comp.